# Notation with a colon that looks like set notation - what is it?

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, trigonometry, notation

I've come across this notation in a task, it says:

*$f(x)=\sin^{-1}x$ and $g(x)=\cos^{-1}x$.* *Show that*
$$\lbrace{x : \cos^{-1}x = \sin^{-1}x}\rbrace = \lbrace x : x= \sqrt{1-x^2} \rbrace$$
*.*

I have no idea what it means. It looks like some kind of set notation but I am not familiar with that topic. Could anyone explain?

Comment: Have you seen the same thing with $\mid$ instead of $:$? They mean the same thing.

Comment: It's interchangable with the notation $\lbrace{x | Cos^{-1}x = Sin^{-1}x}\rbrace = \lbrace x | x= \sqrt{1-x^2} \rbrace$. It's the same thing.

Comment: It means "the set of x-es such that... is equal to the set of x-es, such that...". In other words, same $x$-es satisfy both formulas.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine - Yes, I have always seen this with $|$ so I was confused by $:$, thought it means something else.

Comment: @CiaPan "In other words, same xx-es satisfy both formulas" -  So in other words this is a system of equations? And is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ the only solution?

Comment: Not exactly. They are two equations and the problem is to show they have the same solutions.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. But still there will be one solution for both of them, that is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, right?

Comment: Right. And that implies the described sets of solutions are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is set notation! In words this says the set of all $x$ such that $\sin^{-1}(x) = \cos^{-1}(x)$ is equal to the set of all $x$ such that $x = \sqrt{1-x^2}$. Albeit, this is a slightly lazy notation for it does not specify in which number field they are considering $x$. A more proper description of this equivalence of sets might be

$$\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}: \sin^{-1}(x) = \cos^{-1}(x)\right\} = \left\{x\in \mathbb{R}:x = \sqrt{1-x^2}\right\}$$

and certainly $x$ must lie in the domains of the functions under consideration.

Answer (score 1):

The colon in that context means "such that". You could think of it this way,

If $f(x)=sin^{-1}(x)$ and $g(x)=cos^{-1}(x)$ and $h(x)=\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$,

1. Find all points $x$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$
2. Find all points $x$ such that $x$ = $h(x)$
3. Show that the points from 1 are the same as the points from 2

It may be useful to consider the domain of all the functions defined above.